# Carry fields around, or store and join?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

In Hadoop using Pig, I have a large number of fields in a few separate sources which I load, filter, project, group, run through a couple Java UDFs, join, project and store.  (That's everyday life in Hadoop.)  Some of the fields in the original load of data aren't used by the UDFs and aren't needed until the final store.

> When is it better to pass unused fields through UDFs than to store and join them later?

A trivial toy example is a data source with columns `name,weight,height` and I ultimately want to store `name,weight,heightSquared`.  My UDF is going to square the height for me.  Which is better:

```
inputdata = LOAD 'data' AS name,weight,height;
outputdata = FOREACH inputdata
                GENERATE myudf.squareHeight(name,weight,height)
                AS (name,weight,heightSquared);
STORE outputdata INTO 'output';
```

or

```
inputdata = LOAD 'data' AS name,weight,height;
name_weight = FOREACH inputdata
                GENERATE name,weight;
intdata1 = FOREACH inputdata
                GENERATE myudf.squareHeight(name,height)
                AS (iname,heightSquared);
intdata2 = JOIN intdata1 BY iname, name_weight BY name;
outputdata = FOREACH intdata2
                GENERATE name,weight,heightSquared;
STORE outputdata INTO 'output';
```

In this case it looks pretty obvious: the first case is better.  But the UDF does have to read and store and output the `weight` field.  When you have 15 fields the UDF doesn't care about and one it does, is the first case still better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 15 fields the UDF doesn't care about, then don't send them to the UDF.  In your example, there's no reason to write your UDF to take three fields if it's only going to use the third one.  The best script for your example would be

```
inputdata = LOAD 'data' AS name,weight,height;
outputdata =
    FOREACH inputdata
    GENERATE
        name,
        weight,
        myudf.squareHeight(height) AS heightSquared;
STORE outputdata INTO 'output';
```

So that addresses the UDF case.  If you have a bunch of fields that you'll want to store, but you are not going to use them in any of the next several map-reduce cycles, you may wish to store them immediately and then join them back in.  But that would be a matter of empirically testing which approach is faster for your specific case.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer to the question I asked.  (I'm not sure how to apply it to my *actual* situation where I'm passing databags of tuples to the UDF and get a databag of tuples in return.  I will ask that as a separate question.)

Comment: As an aside, you spent time writing a nice answer but didn't upvote the question.  What makes it fall short of an upvote?

Comment: Bags of tuples are no different. You can use the projection operator to cut your bags down to just the fields that are interesting.  Instead of sending `person` to the UDF with its three fields, just send `person.height`.  Now the UDF is receiving a bag whose tuples have just one field.  Incidentally, I'm not sure that passing too much data to a UDF is a performance issue as much as a maintainability issue. Performance only comes into play if you have several MR cycles, as I mentioned in the second half of the answer.  As to upvotes -- I just don't tend to cast votes on questions, that's all.

Comment: I haven't been able to apply what you write in the above comment to my problem.  I have asked the specific question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711584/cutting-down-bag-to-pass-to-udf