# Cutting down bag to pass to udf

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

Using Pig on a Hadoop cluster, I have a huge `bag` of huge `tuples` which I regularly add fields to as I continue to work on this project, and several UDFs which use various fields from it.  I want to be able to call a UDF on just a few fields from each `tuple` and **reconnect the result to that particular tuple**.  Doing a join to reconnect the records using unique ids takes forever on billions of records.

I think there should be a way to do this all inside the `GENERATE` statement, but I can't find the right syntax.

Here is some toy code using a Python UDF to get the idea across.

```
Register 'jumper.py' using jython as myfuncs;

jumps = LOAD 'jumps.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
   AS (jumper:int, attempt:int, distance:double, location:chararray);

byJumper = GROUP jumps by jumper;

sigmas = FOREACH byJumper GENERATE
    jumps.jumper, jumps.attempt, jumps.distance, jumps.location,
    myfuncs.conv2sigma(jumps.distance);

rmf sigmas
STORE sigmas INTO 'sigmas' USING PigStorage(',');
```

This is producing bags of tuples with single fields in each tuple, rather than tuples of the form I expect.

The input data is

- people (with unique integer IDs),
- their long jump attempts (with unique-to-that-person integer IDs),
- the distance they jumped,
- the location they were jumping at the time.

For each jump we want to generate how many standard deviations (sigmas) the jumper was from their average, then later we'll correlate sigmas by location to see where jumpers do the best.  We need to calculate the average and standard deviation for each person then a 'sigma' for each jump, and store the data with the new sigma field attached.

The question is:

> How do we change this to output tuples like `(jumper:int, attempt:int, distance:double, location:chararray, sigma:double)`?

I have tried `FLATTEN` in various ways and it only gets me enormous cross-products.  I can change my UDF to take in jumper and attempt and output a triple then do a `JOIN`, but in the real world this solution is enormously impractical because of the size of the data sets.

Here's the supporting code and data if you want to try it at home:

jumper.py: (a quick, not thoughtful, implementation -- the only important thing here is that it takes a bag input and produces a bag output with one output tuple corresponding to each input tuple)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# we're forced to use python 2.5.2 :-(

from math import sqrt

@outputSchema("y:bag{t:tuple(sigma:double)}")
def conv2sigma(bag):
    s = 0.0
    n = 0
    dd = []
    print('conv2sigma input bag:')
    print(bag)
    for word in bag:
        d = float(word[0])
        dd.append(d)
        n += 1
        s += d
    a = s / n
    ss = 0
    for d in dd:
        ss += (d-a)**2
    sd = sqrt(ss)
    outputBag = []
    for d in dd:
        outputBag.append( ( (d-a)/sd, ) )
    print('conv2sigma output bag:')
    print(outputBag)
    return outputBag
```

The input file `jumps.csv`:

```
0,0,5,a
0,1,6,b
0,2,7,c
0,3,5,a
0,4,8,c
0,5,7,b
0,6,6,b
0,7,7,c
0,8,5,a
1,0,6,a
1,1,5,a
1,2,7,b
1,3,4,a
1,4,5,a
1,5,7,b
1,6,8,c
1,7,9,c
1,8,5,a
1,9,4,a
1,10,5,a
1,11,6,b
1,12,8,c
1,13,8,b
2,0,7,b
2,1,5,a
2,2,6,b
2,3,5,a
2,4,7,c
2,5,5,a
2,6,6,c
2,7,5,a
2,8,7,b
2,9,5,a
2,10,6,b
```

The output produced as written now:

```
{(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)},{(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(0)},{(6.0),(7.0),(5.0),(8.0),(7.0),(6.0),(7.0),(5.0),(5.0)},{(b),(c),(a),(c),(b),(b),(c),(a),(a)},{(-0.07188851546895898),(0.25160980414135625),(-0.39538683507927425),(0.5751081237516715),(0.25160980414135625),(-0.07188851546895898),(0.25160980414135625),(-0.39538683507927425),(-0.39538683507927425)}
{(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)},{(8),(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13)},{(5.0),(6.0),(5.0),(7.0),(4.0),(5.0),(7.0),(8.0),(9.0),(4.0),(5.0),(6.0),(8.0),(8.0)},{(a),(a),(a),(b),(a),(a),(b),(c),(c),(a),(a),(b),(c),(b)},{(-0.20716308289978433),(-0.03655819109996196),(-0.20716308289978433),(0.1340467006998604),(-0.3777679746996067),(-0.20716308289978433),(0.1340467006998604),(0.30465159249968277),(0.4752564842995052),(-0.3777679746996067),(-0.20716308289978433),(-0.03655819109996196),(0.30465159249968277),(0.30465159249968277)}
{(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2),(2)},{(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)},{(7.0),(5.0),(6.0),(5.0),(7.0),(5.0),(6.0),(5.0),(7.0),(5.0),(6.0)},{(b),(a),(b),(a),(c),(a),(c),(a),(b),(a),(b)},{(0.4276686017238498),(-0.2960782627318961),(0.06579516949597684),(-0.2960782627318961),(0.4276686017238498),(-0.2960782627318961),(0.06579516949597684),(-0.2960782627318961),(0.4276686017238498),(-0.2960782627318961),(0.06579516949597684)}
```

Each output tuple is a collection of bags, and each bag contains tuples with single entries from one field, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do this in two steps. Each jump has its own sigma value, so in order to properly associate each sigma with the correct jump, you will either need to pass the IDs to the sigma-computing UDF and then join the results back in (bad idea), or compute the summary statistics first (mean and standard deviation) and then later derive the sigma from that.  Here's how:

```
jumps = LOAD 'jumps.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
   AS (jumper:int, attempt:int, distance:double, location:chararray);

byJumper = GROUP jumps by jumper;

jumperSummaries =
    FOREACH byJumper
    GENERATE
        group AS jumper,
        FLATTEN(jumps.(attempt, distance, location)),
        myfuncs.mean(jumps.distance) AS mean,
        myfunds.stddev(jumps.distance) AS stddev;

sigmas =
    FOREACH jumperSummaries
    GENERATE
        jumper,
        attempt,
        distance,
        location,
        myfuncs.sigma(distance, mean, stddev) AS sigma;
```

The `FLATTEN` ungroups all the jumps and gives you back your original input, except now every record also has copied the mean and standard deviation for that jumper, which you can then use to compute the sigma for each jump row-by-row.

Note that while this is conceptually two steps, it still only takes one map-reduce job.

Comment: Why `group AS jumper` rather than include it in `FLATTEN(byJumper.(jumper,attempt,distance,location))`?

Comment: That's equivalent.  I just found it a little clearer, because `jumper`, like `mean` and `stddev` has a single value; it doesn't vary among the tuples in `byJumper`. But it's purely a matter of taste.

Comment: I get an error on `FLATTEN(byJumper.(attempt, distance, location))`.  I do not get an error if I instead use `FLATTEN(jumps.(attempt, distance, location))`.  Is this due to my using an old version of Pig (0.9.2), or a typo in the answer?

Comment: That's a typo -- I've fixed it. It's that exact reason that now whenever I project fields after a `GROUP` I just do `$1.distance` so I don't confuse the different aliases....

Comment: This raises a (philosophical?) question for me: is it better to keep as much processing and data handling as possible inside the UDF, or expose it to Pig as your answer does?  I would not naturally choose to create a bag including mean and stddev as you do, I would keep them hidden inside the UDF.

Comment: In general, I would say that it is best to split up the functionality of your UDFs so they are more useful in a variety of circumstances. The sigma calculation you are doing is not at all specific to long jumping. At some point you may find yourself with means and standard deviations and need the sigma, and you'll have to write a new UDF to do that. I'll comment a little more on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For comparison with WinnieNicklaus' answer, and to draw comments, here is the solution I came up with:

```
Register 'jumper.py' using jython as myfuncs;

jumps = LOAD 'jumps.csv' USING PigStorage(',')
   AS (jumper:int, attempt:int, distance:double, location:chararray);

byJumper = GROUP jumps by jumper;

sigmas0 = FOREACH byJumper
    GENERATE
        FLATTEN(jumps),
        FLATTEN(myfuncs.conv2sigma(jumps.(jumper,attempt,distance)));

sigmas1 = FILTER sigmas0 BY jumper == s_id AND attempt == s_att;

sigmas = FOREACH sigmas1
        GENERATE jumper, attempt, distance, location, sigma;

rmf sigmas
STORE sigmas INTO 'sigmas' USING PigStorage(',');
```

The first `FOREACH` creates a (potentially large) cross product `sigma0`, filters out the "incorrect" elements of the product and generates the desired fields.  `JOIN` is often academically described this way.

This seems like it may be slow.

But it still results in a single Map-Reduce job, and *seems* to be fast in practice.

The huge win for me is that it allows my UDF to do arbitrarily complicated things and return arbitrarily many tuples which are rejoined to the input data.

Comment: "Arbitrarily complicated things" is a red flag to me. You're certainly free to do that, but in my experience that comes at the cost of inflexibility down the road. IMHO, modularity is almost always to be recommended. http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/modularitychapter.html

Comment: That's a good point.  I have definitely taken an anti-modular approach to this project so far, which makes it hard to maintain.  The best solution will, of course, be somewhere in the middle -- not everything can be done in an entirely modular fashion, but a large part of it can be modular.